# google bigquery the count of each string into one table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We want to query this table:

```
Row bucket  action  count    
1   1407974 aaaaaa  15   
2   1407974 bbbbbb  67   
3   1407369 aaaaaa  89   
4   1407369 bbbbbb  501
```

to this output:

```
Row bucket  actionA actionB  
1   1407974 15      67   
3   1407369 89      501
```

What is the cheapest way to query with google bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  bucket, MAX(actionA) actionA, MAX(actionB) actionB
FROM (
  SELECT 
    bucket,
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(action, 'aaaaaa') THEN count END actionA, 
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(action, 'bbbbbb') THEN count END actionB
  FROM [tmp.a]
) GROUP BY bucket
```